# angularjs FileReader return undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filereader

I can't seem to get the text string from the upload file. Before it used to work in my controller. Somehow, it stops working and console.log($scope.importFile) show 'undefined'. I'm kind of new to both handling file upload and angularjs. Can you help pinpoint what went wrong?

My directive and controller and HTML:

```js
app.directive('fileReader', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fileReader:"="
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $(element).on('change', function(changeEvent) {
        var files = changeEvent.target.files;
        //console.log(files.length);
        
        if (files.length) {
          var r = new FileReader();
          r.onload = function(e) {
              var contents = e.target.result;
              scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.fileReader = contents;
              });
              //console.log(scope.fileReader + ' in onload');
              //r.readAsText(files[0]);
          };
          console.log('using file-reader directive');
          console.log(r.readAsText(files[0]));
          r.readAsText(files[0]);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});



app.controller('NavController', function($scope, $location, $modal, toaster) {
  
  $scope.selectFile = function () {
      console.log('print upload: '+ $scope.importFile );
      alert('print upload: '+ $scope.importFile);
  };
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group">             
   <input type="file" file-reader="importFile" class="form-control"/><br>      
 </div>     
 
<div class="form-group">
 <label>
   <input class="pull-left text-left col-sm-1 control-label" type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmDeleteMode">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash col-sm-10 pull-left text-left">
       <em style="color:red">By checking this box, I understand....</em>
     </span>  
  </label>
</div>
         
<div class="form-group">       
   <input type="button" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-inverse" ng-click="selectFile()" ng-disabled="!confirmDeleteMode">
         
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, you have a syntax error at the last line of your JavaScript

```
app.controller('NavController', function($scope, $location, $modal, toaster) {

  $scope.selectFile = function () {
      console.log('print upload: '+ $scope.importFile );
      alert('print upload: '+ $scope.importFile);
  };
};
```

Where you forgot to close the parenthesis. JavaScript console should inform you that.

```
app.controller('NavController', function($scope, $location, $modal, toaster) {

  $scope.selectFile = function () {
      console.log('print upload: '+ $scope.importFile );
      alert('print upload: '+ $scope.importFile);
  };
}); // <- Here
```

Secondly, though doesn't matter, `$(element)` is redundant. AngularJS provides a severely stripped-down implementation that mimics jQuery called jqLite. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). That's a lot like jQuery, but not really. (There actually are significant behavior differences even in supported features. So be careful with that.) All elements given by AngularJS are already wrapped in jqLite. Furthermore, if you really want jQuery, simply import jQuery before AngularJS and AngularJS will pick it up and use jQuery instead of its jqLite. So here `element` is already wrapped in jQuery. Another word of caution, AngularJS 2.0 is going to completely [drop the whole jqLite thing](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/preparing-for-the-future-of-angularjs#2-3-6-jqlite), because DOM these days is powerful enough.

Otherwise it works fine. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pma83egk/)